# bbPress plugin: forum lists not showing in correct order?

Tags: plugins, functions, bbpress, order, forum

I'm running Wordpress 3.3.1 and bbPress 2.1 (plugin, not standalone)

my forums are are not being listed in the front page archive or forum summary pages in the correct order; I double checked many times the ordering number, but no matter what, the forums will display in their own order which is neither alphabetical, cronological (date created/updated) or other. I can't just figure it out.

I've tried also re-arranging forums with simple page ordering plugin, no success. I've disabled my custom theme and tried with TwentyTen. I've disabled all my other plugins, but situation hasn't changed.

All my forums were imported from a previous bbPress 1.x standalone installation. Forum works overall fine, except by this bug that disallows me to arrange the order of the forums in the archives...

I've posted this question also on the bbPress forums, but so far we haven't found a solution:
http://bbpress.org/forums/topic/bbpress-2-plugin-forum-order-doesnt-work-not-appearing-in-correct-order

thanks